# How do I show the total number of sales orders per year for each sales representative using CTE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been trying to show the total number of sales orders per year for each sales representative using CTE but my logic is messed up. I don't even know what I'm doing?

```
WITH TotalNumber
AS (
    -- Query Here
    SELECT SalesPersonID
        ,SalesOrderID
        ,YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY SalesYear ASC
    )
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(OrderDate)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Comment: You don't need CTE's for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way

```
SELECT SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS Total_number_of _sales_orders  
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader  
WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate)
ORDER BY SalesYear ASC
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Alucard Nemesis